# How to make changes after deploying Angular CLI app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Can we make changes after deploying Angular CLI application.
Or we always need to build it and deploy total new one again ?

Comment: Always build and deploy again.

Answer (score 1):

You **can not** add new features to a deployed application **once its built**. If you need to add new features to your application you have to **add them locally and build it again and deploy it**.

Comment: Please add such answer as comments or elaborate in detail as a proper answer. This is not worthy of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*technically* **YES**, you can edit the main.js file. 
but it is much easier to build and re-deploy.